# ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean __main__ is not a package?

Tags: python, module, python-3.6, python-import

I am trying to run a module from the console. The structure of my directory is this:

[image]

I am trying to run the module `p_03_using_bisection_search.py`, from the `problem_set_02` directory using:

```
$ python3 p_03_using_bisection_search.py
```

The code inside `p_03_using_bisection_search.py`is:

```
__author__ = 'm'


from .p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after


def compute_bounds(balance: float,
                   annual_interest_rate: float) -> (float, float):

    # there is code here, but I have omitted it to save space
    pass


def compute_lowest_payment(balance: float,
                           annual_interest_rate: float) -> float:

    # there is code here, but I have omitted it to save space
    pass    

def main():
    balance = eval(input('Enter the initial balance: '))
    annual_interest_rate = eval(input('Enter the annual interest rate: '))

    lowest_payment = compute_lowest_payment(balance, annual_interest_rate)
    print('Lowest Payment: ' + str(lowest_payment))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am importing a function that is in `p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year.py` which code is:

```
__author__ = 'm'


def compute_balance(balance: float,
                    fixed_payment: float,
                    annual_interest_rate: float) -> float:

    # this is code that has been omitted
    pass


def compute_balance_after(balance: float,
                          fixed_payment: float,
                          annual_interest_rate: float,
                          months: int=12) -> float:

    # Omitted code
    pass


def compute_fixed_monthly_payment(balance: float,
                                  annual_interest_rate: float) -> float:

    # omitted code
    pass


def main():
    balance = eval(input('Enter the initial balance: '))
    annual_interest_rate = eval(
        input('Enter the annual interest rate as a decimal: '))
    lowest_payment = compute_fixed_monthly_payment(balance,
                                                   annual_interest_rate)
    print('Lowest Payment: ' + str(lowest_payment))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue. I have tried adding a `__init__.py` file, but it is still not working.

Comment: Not your issue, but I just wanted to throw it out there: `eval(input...` probably isn't a great idea. I'd just parse it instead of opening up the opportunity for arbitrary code execution.

Comment: i'd bet that `eval(input(...` bit was suggested by 2to3.  I had it do that to me today. glad I don't follow it's suggestions blindling

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Simply remove the dot for the relative import and do:

```
from p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

Comment: you solve it. Why is the relative import not working even if I add `__init__.py`?

Comment: The accepted answer is not working for me. Could you possibly expand the answer by adding a minimalistic example setup?

Comment: from myclass import SomeClass, here I got error for myclass and SomeClass but still this got worked for me.

Comment: This works for me (inside a package, i.e. with an empty `__init__.py` in the same folder), although my PyCharm (2018.2.4) marks this as an "Unresolved reference" and fails to autocomplete the import.

Comment: @djvg - To fix PyCharm you can mark root directory as source root

Comment: Warning: This fails when you create an `entry_point` console_script in `setup.py` while distributing the package. Also, VSCode fails to parse this (although thats the editor's fault).

Comment: Working with Python's imports is infuriating. It is like Python 3, PyCharm, and MyPy are all having a big laugh at our expense. How is it that `from ..sibling_pkg.nephew import my_function` is valid for PyCharm, but results in `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` and MyPy `Cannot find module named '.sibling_pkg.nephew'` (note a single "." in the error, not two). Yet, `from sibling_pkg.nephew import my_function` works as intended, doesn't have a MyPy error, but does result in a PyCharm error.

Comment: I fixed this error by not naming my main script the same thing as its parent directory. I had my main script "app.py" in a folder "app", i.e. `app/app.py`. It contained the line `import app.lib`, which was intended to import the module `app/lib.py`. Raises `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.lib'; 'app' is not a package`. Fixed by renaming `app/app.py` to `app/blabla.py`.

Comment: Extending the comment from @DenisYakovlev: To mark a directory as a sources root in PyCharm just right-click, "Mark Directory As", "Sources Root".

Comment: @ubiquibacon may you never have the misfortune of trying to work with dependencies for any medium/large application.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, please explain why removing a dot works and not otherwise. Thank you

Answer (score 113):

I have the same issue as you did. I think the problem is that you used relative import in `in-package import`. There is no `__init__.py` in your directory. So just import as Moses answered above.

The core issue I think is when you import with a dot:

```
from .p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

It is equivalent to:

```
from __main__.p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

where `__main__` refers to your current module `p_03_using_bisection_search.py`.

---

**Briefly, the interpreter does not know your directory architecture.**

When the interpreter get in `p_03.py`, the script equals:

```
from p_03_using_bisection_search.p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

and `p_03_using_bisection_search` does not contain any modules or instances called `p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year`.

---

So I came up with a cleaner solution without changing python environment valuables (after looking up how [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py) do in relative import):

The main architecture of the directory is:

```
main.py
setup.py
problem_set_02/
   __init__.py
   p01.py
   p02.py
   p03.py
```

Then write in `__init__.py`:

```
from .p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

Here `__main__` is `__init__` , it exactly refers to the module `problem_set_02`.

Then go to `main.py`:

`import problem_set_02`

You can also write a `setup.py` to add specific module to the environment.

Answer (score 12):

Try to run it as:

`python3 -m p_03_using_bisection_search`

Answer (score 6):

Just use the name of the main folder which the .py file is in.

```
from problem_set_02.p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the dot and import absolute_import in the beginning of your file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from p_02_paying_debt_off_in_a_year import compute_balance_after
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have created directory and sub-directory, follow the steps below and please keep in mind all directory must have  `__init__.py` to get it recognized as a directory.

1. In your script, include `import sys` and `sys.path`, you will be able to see all the paths available to Python. You must be able to see your current working directory.
2. Now import sub-directory and respective module that you want to use using: `import subdir.subdir.modulename as abc` and now you can use the methods in that module.

[image]

As an example, you can see in this screenshot I have one parent directory and two sub-directories  and under second sub-directories I have the module `CommonFunction`. On the right my console shows that after execution of `sys.path`, I can see my working directory.