# How to run a python program like pycharm does

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.6

I've been developing a project in python for some time using pycharm. I have no problem running it in pycharm, but I want to try and running it from the command line (I'm using windows). 
When I try to run my main file using  `python <filename>` from within the root directory, I get a module not found error. What is pycharm doing/how can i replicate it? 
Also, pycharm creates **pycache** folders. If my understanding is correct its compiling the files, and that makes the runtime faster. Since my runtime is already long i'd like to do the same.

I'm using python 3.6

### edit

File Structure

```
    -Root\
    ----scheduler\
        ------main.py
        ------matrices
        ------models
        ------rhc
        ------Singleton.py
        ------utils.py
        ------__init__.py
        ------apis\
                acedb.py
                metrics.py
                __init__.py
        ------matrices\
                distancematrix.py
                __init__.py
        ------models\
                branch.py
                constants.py
                customer.py
                dispatch.py
                technician.py
                workorder.py
                __init__.py
        ------rhc\
                pathfinder.py
                rhc.py
                schedule.py
                sched_time.py
                tech_schedule.py
                __init__.py
```

### Edit 2

Found the solution, i had to move my main files outside of the modules
Thanks!

Comment: pycache is created by the interpreter, not the IDE. It contains bytecode. It's not exactly compiled, and it doesn't really affect the runtime (it always runs the bytecode, anyway).

Comment: You are getting the error probably because of the way that PyCharm structures your project. Could you post a chart that shows the directory structure of all of the files that you have for your program and also the error message that you get?

Comment: Make sure that the python executable run with 'python' on the command line is the same as the python used by PyCharm.  Run `import sys; print(sys.executable)` with each.  If they are different, you need to duplicate the needed modules in the `site-modules` for each.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r i posted the file structure in an edit just now and im getting a ModuleNotFoundErro

Comment: @TerryJanReedy just checked and they are not different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the below folder structure for instance. add an empty file named **init**.py and import from your app.py, in case you have a Module1Class , you can always import it like this

```
from modules.module1 import Module1Class
from modules.module2 import Module2Class
```

Folder structure

```
/app.py
/modules
    /module1.py
    /module2.py
    /__init__.py
```

The first time you rum app.py from terminal like python app.py, the .pyc files will be created, leaving you with the following folder structure

```
/app.py
/modules
    /module1.py
    /module1.pyc
    /module2.py
    /module2.pyc
    /__init__.py
```

Please refer to the python documentation as it's very well documented on how to create modules and importing them. I'm more used to python2.7 , so my answer might not be an exact fit to newer python versions.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

From there you can learn more about __ init __.py and module creation , exporting and importing

PS: I use only text editors to develop in python, as I find pycharm a bit on the heavy side, so I cannot explain how exactly pycharm works behind the curtains.

Comment: I have these __init__.py files in all modules already (just posted file structure).

Answer (score 0):

see [ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean __main__ is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package) for a good example of ModuleNotFoundError description (was answered fast)

I bet that pycharm is configured to use a different python interpreter of virtual environment.