# how to import file.py from main folder if you are working in a subfolder python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a structure such has:

```
/mainfolder
file.py
    //subfolder
    test.py
```

I am trying to import `file.py` in `test.py`. for some reason I just can't.

I tried

```
from .file import *
```

returning :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.file'; '__main__' is not a package
```

also tried to add path to sys.path:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.extend([os.getcwd()])
```

doesnt work either

Comment: Side note: you should be working with packages not folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running `test.py` with `python test.py` and as such the `test` module is being treated as a top level module.

You should first make your folders Python packages if they are not by adding `__init__.py` files:

```
/mainfolder
__init__.py
file.py
    /subfolder
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

Then you can append the outer `mainfolder` to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..'))
```

After which `from file import someobject` without relative import works. Be wary of wild card imports.

See [ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean __main__ is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package/41817024#41817024) and [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python/73149#73149) for more on why your current approach does not work.

Comment: assuming that I have a test2.py in //subfolder and test.py has from file import * at the start, how can I import test.py in test2.py?

Comment: Discard `import *`. Specify explicitly what you want to have imported. If `subfolder` is a subpackage, then `import .test` or `from mainfolder.subfolder import test` should be fine

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using? I am using Pycharm Community IDE with Python 3 and it works with `from file import *` or `from file import some_function` (I wanted to comment but I can't since I don't have 50 reputation yet)