# Python 3 - importing .py file in same directory - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.char'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.  I have 2 .py files in the same directory, `char.py`, and `char_user.py`, as follows:

char.py:

```
# char.py

import cv2

#######################################################################################################################
class Char:

    # constructor #####################################################################################################
    def __init__(self):
        self.contour = None
        self.centerOfMassX = None
        self.centerOfMassY = None
    # end def

# end class
```

char_user.py:

```
# char_user.py

import os
import cv2

# I've tried this various ways, see more comments below
from .char import Char

#######################################################################################################################
def main():

    char = Char()

    char.centerOfMassX = 0
    char.centerOfMassY = 0

    print("finished main() without error")
# end main

#######################################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

No matter what I try, on the line in `char_user.py` where I'm attempting to import file char.py, class Char, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.char'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Here are some of the ways I've tried the import statement in `char_user.py`:

```
from .char import Char
from . import Char
import Char
import char
```

I've tried both with and without an empty `__init__.py` in the same directory.

I've consulted these posts but none have been able to provide a resolution:

[How to import the class within the same directory or sub directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory)

[ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean __main__ is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package)

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.xxxx'; '__main__' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446418/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-main-xxxx-main-is-not-a-packag)

This is the 1st time in Python 3 I've attempted to import a script that I wrote in the same directory (done this many times in Python 2 without concern).

Is there a way to do this?  What am I missing?

Comment: This works fine if I use `from char import Char` or just use `import char`. Use `.` would only work if there was a sub-package structure. So, I cannot reproduce this error.

Comment: Could you explain why there's a dot here? `from .char import Char`

Comment: @YunkaiXiao it's an [intrapackage import](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:
`from char import Char`

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get this working with `from char import Char`, because you are trying to import the class `Char` from script `char`.

As far as I am aware, the line `from .char import Char` is only used if both files were part of a python module (with its own `__init__.py`), which they are not. In that case, `.char` explicitly references the file `char.py` inside the same module folder, rather than from importing from some other module installed to PYTHONPATH.