# No module named '__main__.demo'; '__main__' is not a package python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

If I execute `main.py` it works fine, the problem is when I execute `demo2.py`

```
|myPackage
   |subPackage
      demo.py
      demo2.py
   main.py
```

main.py

```
from ludikDriver.demo2 import demo2_print

demo2_print()
```

demo2.py

```
from .demo import demoprint

def demo2_print():
    print("demo2")
    demoprint()

demo2_print()
```

demo.py

```
def demoprint():
    print("demo")
```

Error: `from .demo import demoprint`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.demo'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Should I have `__init__.py`?

Comment: It looks like you're running this as `python demo2.py` from the command line?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45446418/7954504, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41816973/7954504,

Answer (score 8):

If you drop the `.`, it should work. `demo2.py` becomes:

```py
from demo import demoprint # instead of `from .demo import demoprint`

def demo2_print():
    print("demo2")
    demoprint()

demo2_print()
```

Now you can run `%run ludikDriver/demo2.py` in ipython for instance and you get:

```
demo2
demo
```

For more details, the section "Imports" of [this article](https://hackaday.com/2018/08/15/stop-using-python-2-what-you-need-to-know-about-python-3/) might help.

Comment: Thats a great article! Thank you.