# Python 3 ModuleNotFound Error no module names __main__.my_module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error in my project where I cannot import my code. I am not sure why this is happening, as I've never run into this issue before.

I have consulted these questions:

[ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean **main** is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package)

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.xxxx'; '**main**' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446418/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-main-xxxx-main-is-not-a-packag)

[No module named '**main**.demo'; '**main**' is not a package python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157314/no-module-named-main-demo-main-is-not-a-package-python3)

My project's setup looks like this:

```
-code
    -__init__.py
    -my_module.py
    -driver.py
-tests
    -__init__.py
    -test_my_module.py
```

When trying to execute the following code:

```py
from .my_module import MyModule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_mod = MyModule()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .my_module import MyModule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.my_module'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I am running this when in the code directory. I have tried the following imports as well:

```py
from code.my_module import MyModule
from ..my_module import MyModule
import my_module.MyModule
import MyModule
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the code you're try to execute `driver.py`? If not, where is it located relative to your project's setup?

Comment: Yes, that is the code I am trying to execute. It is in the code directory.

Comment: Since `my_module.py` is in the same directory as `driver.py`, I think all you need is `from my_module import MyModule` — assuming there's something named `MyModule` defined in `my_module.py`.