# Understanding how the Python3 import method works

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I've been working on a python3 application and I ran into a strange problem that picked my curiosity after annoying me greatly.

My file structure is something like this:

```
root/
 |   __init__.py
 |   main.py
 |   fuzzy/
     |    __init__.py
     |    foo.py
 |   dreamy/
     |    __init__.py
     |    bar.py
     |    meh.py
```

So I need to use a method of the `foo` module in both `bar` and `meh`.

In `bar` I wrote:

```
from fuzzy.foo import foo_function
```

And that worked perfectly fine.

Now in `meh` I used the exact same syntax but ended up with an import error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fuzzy'
```

I managed to solve the problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python) method, but I would like to understand why this happens.

According to the [Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) my import syntax is correct:

> An alternative way of importing the submodule is:
>
> `from sound.effects import echo`

This seems to also be the syntax provided by [answered question on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826201/10964544)

Moreover, both `bar` and `meh` are in the same directory and their code starts in exactly the same way.

Does anyone know why this error occurs in one file but not in the other ?

Is there something I did wrong ?

If I did do something wrong, what would be the correct way (or good practices) to import local packages / methods ?

Thanks for your insight.

---EDIT---

I did not fiddle with my `PYTHONPATH` in any way, and I am running Python3 from a (vanilla) Conda venv. For good measures, I also created a new file structure and copied the code in new, blank files. This was to make sure that nothing "funny" would have happened to my directory.

Comment: `import foo` shouldn't work as old-style relative imports are unsupported in Python 3. You most likely did something funny with your current directory or your `PYTHONPATH`. No way for us to know.

Comment: @jpmc26 Thanks for the input. However I did not fiddle with my `PYTHONPATH` in any way. I'm running my code on a vanilla Conda ve. Could you please give me a bit more info as to why `from foo import foo` shouldn't work ? According to the [Python3 official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) it should still work.

Comment: Read PEP 328. It talks about removing the functionality your import relies on and the ambiguity it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be terribly simple, however I did notice that other people struggled with it.

Though I found the answer to my question thanks to [Baum mit Augen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3002139/baum-mit-augen).

Baum mit Augen took the time to write [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/10964544) which is very instructive and well written.

So sum my problem up:
In development, I tried to call my functions by launching my bar.py from the terminal. This means bar is the **main**, but located inside a package subdirectory. This causes an Import Error because "its name does not reveal that it is in a package".

I just want to highlight 2 things unrelated to my question:

1. Considering the post on which I have found this answer this is NOT an easy problem. FYI: I had a quick chat with a Python developer who couldn't find the words to explain this to me.
2. I find it incredible that those who seek help with valid questions are basically being answered to "RTFM", arch-linux style. I really find it a pity.