# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main' but path seems correct

Tags: python, apache-beam

The structure of `my_dir` is

```
├── README.md
├── main
│   ├── functions
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── my_function.py
│   ├── pipeline.py
│   ├── options
│   │   └── pipeline_options.py
│   └── transforms
│       ├── __pycache__
│       ├── my_transform.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
```

On `pipeline.py`:

```
from main.functions.my_function import MyFunction
```

On `my_function.py`:

```
import apache_beam as beam

class MyFunction(beam.DoFn):
...
```

I have read similar questions here, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446418/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-main-xxxx-main-is-not-a-packag) which is the solution I have currently. Also read [this](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) on Python imports.

When I run `pipeline.py`, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipeline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from main.functions.my_function import MyFunction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

Additionally, I'm using VSCode and if I run the file via "Python: Run Python File in Terminal" I get back the error. However, if I run via the debugger the paths are all found and the error is not thrown, which I found odd. Also, VSCode isn't throwing any path warnings.

I know there are similar questions but I haven't been able to figure out what is wrong here and have spent quite some time on this already. Any help/pointer is much appreciated.

### Additional info

- I'm using python 3.8.1
- Using `poetry run python main/pipeline.py` to run the code
- Running from command from `my_dir`

Comment: Have you tried adding `__init__.py` files to your directories to indicate they should be treated as packages?

Comment: in pipeline you should directly call ```from functions.my_function import MyFunction```

Comment: I had before but I'm using python 3.8.1 and `__init__` files are only needed for Python <3.5

Comment: I have tried that too, it returns the same error and is also flagged by VSCode (`unresolved import 'functions.my_function'Python(unresolved-import)`)

Comment: @mcansado Are you running your Python file from the directory where main directory is located? Or are you running it from main directory?

Comment: Running it from where main is located (meaning if I run `ls`, `main` is in the results)

Comment: Have you tried to do in your pipeline.py script before the imports statments : `os.sys.path.append('../main/functions')` and after that you only do `from my_function import MyFunction`