# Python 3.x import class module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-import, importerror

Trying to import a class into my Python code from another .py file I've written and included in the same sub-directory, however I'm receiving the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.S_DES_Functions'; '**main**' is not a package

Please find below images of the layout of my Python project.

[image: Class I'm trying to import][image: Main file running program, trying to import class]

I'm hoping this is just a really silly mistake I'm making, so if anyone can please advise what I'm doing wrong that'd be great :)

Comment: python doesn't use semi colons. Also did you try [removing the dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package)?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749411/4421870 and get rid of the semi colons

Comment: Can you see the contents of the directory in code completion look up when you type `from .`?

Comment: How are you running the code where you get the error? Are you doing `python some_script.py` where the script file is in the same package as the rest of your code? That won't work because Python won't realize the main module is in a package. A better way is to change directory to be above the package, then run `python -m package.script_module`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, I tried them however was still receiving the same error. But I managed to find a work around, similar to what is listed in this other Stack Overflow question - [Unresolved reference issue in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236824/unresolved-reference-issue-in-pycharm)

I basically made a new directory for my classes and set it as the directory as a "Source" for the project, which then allowed me to import it and use the classes without any issues.