# Cannot import module. "No module named ..."

Tags: python, module

I have 2 files, tictactoe.py and tictactoe_functions.py. Both are in the same folder and tictactoe.py starts off by importing the other function via

```
import tictactoe_functions
```

This gives the error message "No module named tictactoe_functions".

I have tried this on a school computer and it works there, but not on my private computer. School computer runs linux and this one uses Windows 8 if that's relevant.

How do I solve this so it's possible to import the module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean \_\_main\_\_ is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package)

Comment: try from tictactoe_functions import *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python)

Comment: Can you describe your execution environment, how you start your program? Are you typing `python tictactoe.py` in a CMD window? Are you double-clicking the `ticktactoe.py` file? Are you running your program from IDLE or from some other IDE?