# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Tags: python, import, module, package, python-import

I have a package with the following structure:

```
model\
    __init__.py (from model.main_trainer import *, etc.)
    main_trainer.py
    snn.py
    splitter.py
```

The main_trainer.py script takes at least three arguments as inputs:

```
#main_trainer.py

import numpy as np # Linear algebra
import pandas as pd # Data wrangling
import re # Regular expressions

import matplotlib


# Avoid plotting graphs
matplotlib.use('Agg')

# Custom dependencies
from model.snn import *
from model.splitter import *

def main_trainer(dataset_name, model_dict = None, train_dict = None,
                 how = 'k-fold cross-validation', save = True):
    etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset_name, model_dict, train_dict, how = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4]
    main_trainer(dataset_name, model_dict, train_dict, how)
```

However, if I run in the terminal the following:

```
python main_trainer.py dataset_name model_dict train_dict 'k-fold cross-validation'
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_trainer.py", line 17, in <module>
    from model.snn import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

On the other hand, if I use the relative path as such:

```
# Custom dependencies
from .snn import *
from .splitter import *
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_trainer.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .snn import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.snn'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I have also tried running it as:

```
python -m main_trainer ...
```

and then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kdqm927/miniconda3/envs/siamese/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/kdqm927/miniconda3/envs/siamese/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/projects/cc/kdqm927/PythonNotebooks/model/main_trainer.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .snn import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I have checked these posts to no avail:
[ModuleNotFoundError: What does it mean __main__ is not a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816973/modulenotfounderror-what-does-it-mean-main-is-not-a-package),
[Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Append your script/module path with `sys` module then import your sub modules.

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/model/modules/')
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

**Edit:**

Modified your `main_trainer` file

```
#main_trainer.py

import numpy as np # Linear algebra
import pandas as pd # Data wrangling
import re # Regular expressions
import sys
import matplotlib


# Avoid plotting graphs
matplotlib.use('Agg')

# Custom dependencies
sys.path.append('/projects/cc/kdqm927/PythonNotebooks/model/') #folder which contains model, snn etc.,
from snn import *
from splitter import *
```

Comment: So I should be adding this to each and every module?

Comment: The place where you're importing specific libraries. `from model.snn import *` and `from model.splitter import *`

Comment: so sys.path.append('/path/../model/') in my main_trainer.py script,  sys.path.append('/path/../model/main_trainer/') or sys.path.append('/path/../model/snn/') and sys.path.append('/path/../model/splitter/')

Comment: If I add sys.path.append('path/to/my/projects/'), the folder which contains the model folder, which in turn contains the modules, I get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_trainer.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .snn import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.snn'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: you might be using that `mail.snn`, I can't say without seeing your code, but I did one more edit where your can point till the model folder and them do `import snn` and `splitter` separately

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify that I am using if __name__ == '__main__' at the end of the function in main_trainer, sorry for not mentioning it before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215909/discussion-between-vanarajan-natarajan-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

According to the results of my own operation, this problem was solved exactly:

1. Install modAL-python in Anaconda Prompt (pip install modAL-python)
2. Enter python in Anaconda Prompt ((base) C:\Users\TEST>python)
3. Execute the statement in the python environment of the second step: import modAL
4. Execution statement: help(modAL)
5. Restart the application that is using modAL.